# Why bootstrap is not converting to responsive my static-nav top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im working on the following page:

however, if you zoom in to 175% you can see how the top nav get's in a second line.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/)  that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By choosing an earlier break-point for your navigation to collapse. Right now it collapses at 768px. If you increase it to 995px it works with your design.

```
@media (min-width: 995px)
.container > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse {
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
}
```